# Need (solid) proof for finding a maximum value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Can anyone please verify my logic to find maximum value of a function?

here is my work:

Goal is to find $x,y$ which maximize $f(x,y)$

($f(x,y)$ is a function developed by myself)

only $y$ has a restriction in range, $0<= y <= 1$

1. I found that at any given $y$,  $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} < 0$, (strictly concave at any given $y$)

   and there always exists $x^*$ satisfying $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = 0$ (at any given $y$)

   So I think $x^*$ is a function of $y$, and it is the value of $x$ which maximizes $f(x,y)$ at given $y$, so $x^* = x^*(y)$
2. So I subsituted $x$ with $x^*(y)$ in the original function, $f(x^*(y),y)$. Therefore $f(x^*(y),y)$ is a function of $y$ since $x^*(y)$ is a function of $y$
3. Now I found that $\frac{\partial^2 f(x^*(y),y)}{\partial y^2} > 0 $ (or should it be $\frac{d^2 f(x^*(y),y)}{d y^2}$ since it is a function of $y$ only). That means the function is strictly convex for any given $y$.
4. So either $f(x^*(0),0)$ or $f(x^*(1),1)$ should be the maximum value of the function $f(x,y)$, since $0<= y <= 1$.

Now an important person says that I have to check second derivative test for my solution. 
I don't understand.. second derivative test only works when the points are stationary, and in my case they are not.

What should I do to strengthen my proof? What am I missing?

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Aside from the issue whether your $x^{*}(y)$ is really a $C^2$ function which allow you to calculate $\frac{\partial^2f(x^{*}(y),y)}{\partial y^2}$, your arguments looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really needed the confirmation. Although I have no idea about why he or she mentioned second derivative test.. ^^;

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. At the end you have to maximize the function $$y\mapsto\psi(y):=f\bigl(x^*(y),y\bigr)\qquad(0\leq y\leq1)\ .$$
This function has turned out to be twice differentiable with $\psi''(y)>0$. It therefore could have a stationary point in the interior of $[0,1]$, but this point would then automatically be a local minimum of $\psi$.

On the other hand, as $\psi$ is continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$ it is bound to assume a global maximum on this interval, and the only candidates left are $y=0$ and $y=1$. It follows that the global maximum of your function $f$ on its domain $\Omega:=\{(x,y)\ |\ 0\leq y\leq 1,\ a(y)<x<b(y)\}$ is given by $\max\{\psi(0),\psi(1)\}$.